# views duplicates fields when node contains two multi-valued fields. 

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

### Here is my set-up:

I define a nodetype that contains both a multi-valued filefield ("field_myfilefields)" and a multi-valued emvideo field ("field_myemvideos").
I create a node of this type, and (eg) populate it with two filefields and three emvideos.
I define a view, with these fields:  field_myfilefields, field_myemfields.

### What I would like:

In this example, I would like views to create five rows, with one video per row.

### What I get:

Views creates 6 rows, where each row contains both a filefield and an emvideo field:

- row 0: filefield 0, emvideo 0
- row 1: filefield 0, emvideo 1
- row 2: filefield 0, emvideo 2
- row 3: filefield 1, emvideo 0
- row 4: filefield 1, emvideo 1
- row 5: filefield 1, emvideo 2

That is, views cycles through the filefields, and for each filefield cycles through the emfields.  Each video gets displayed twice.  I can understand why views does this, but it is not what I want and I am hoping this is a work-around.

Any suggestions on how I can enforce one video per row, and avoid duplicate videos?

P.S.  I tried experimenting with views' "group multiple values" checkbox.  But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: when you define the view to show two fields, it will show two fields. I think you need to separate your view to 2 views, one for field_myfilefields, and one for field_myemfields. or, you can use the altering function of the view to change the views db query

Comment: Looking at the views 2 UI, I do not see an option to alter the db query.  Where would I find this option?  Thank you.

Comment: well, you'll have to build a new module, and then use [views hook](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/group/views_hooks/6) or in specific [hook_views_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/6) . i don't think its the right solution. i would build two separate views, if it were up to me..

Comment: Thanks very much.  After further thought, I will take your recommendation, create two different views, and use the views API to combine the two sets of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that in Views 2 for Drupal 6 there is a "distinct" setting for the view, which is intended solely for that purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the problem.  I checked "distinct", and views now outputs just a single row, containing the first filefield and the first emfield.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you describe your filters, relationships etc for the view?

Comment: For now, it's a pretty basic view.  There are no filters and no relationships.  Just the two fields described above.  All other settings are default.

Comment: I see, it looks like you got the help you needed from the comments to your question. I hope it worked out!